# Passing variable through ajax on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I am passing variable to `add_user.php` ,now I want to pass same variable to another page `countuser.php`is it possible to pass variable to two pages right from this code?

```
var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
var datastring = 'user_id='+ user_id ;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "add_user.php",
data: datastring,
success: function(html){}
```

Comment: aftee add_user send other ajax request to countuser.php

Comment: Perhaps, it will help: "Multiple Simultaneous Ajax Requests (with one callback) in jQuery"  https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/

Answer (score 4):

Use each for array elements. If next time will be some other page you can add in array

```
var pages = [ "add_user.php", "countuser.php" ];
var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
var datastring = 'user_id='+ user_id ;

jQuery.each( pages, function( i, val ) {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: val,
  data: datastring,
  success: function(html){}
});
```